# Canon TS3100 Printer

Tags: pi-3b+

When I run Rasbian with my Canon TS3100 printer simple scan won’t recognize my printer but if I install The latest Debian it recognizes the scanner usb and wirelessly

Comment: please ask a question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.